# What is the alternate of shared preference in flutter

Tags: flutter, null, sharedpreferences, alternate

I am developed an app, which is almost complete it is in deployment stage. But, now i am in huge problem, i uninstall the app from emulator and then run it again and it sends me the error of `shared preference` version, that flutter updates it version from `2.0.5` to `2.0.7` so i change the version of `shared preference` from `2.0.5` to `2.0.7`, then when i run the app it builds successfully but i can't move to next screen. my api is running it is sending me `200` response status code.

i am using `shared preference` in login screen, so that when user logged in i am getting its all details in `response.data` and then passing the data from login screen to home and other screen using `shared preference`.

here is the login function code

```
var data={};
  Future login() async {
    Dio dio = new Dio();
    
    try {  
      data = {
        'username':"abc",
        'password':"abc123",
        'date': "2021-08-29"
      }; 
     await dio
          .post(localhostUrlLogin, data: json.encode(data),)
          .then((onResponse) async {
          print(onResponse.statusCode);

        String name = (onResponse.data['User']['username']);    
        String email = (onResponse.data['User']['email']);

      //here i am using shared preference to pass the name and email to home and other screen
        myPrefs.setString('name', name);
        myPrefs.setString('email', email);

//here i am calling the home screen
        Navigator.push(
              context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()));
      
      });
    } catch (e) {
         showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return AdvanceCustomAlert(
                title: "Connection Error",
                descriptions: "Connection error",
                icon: Icons.error,
                bgcolor: Colors.red,
                fgcolor: Colors.red,
              );
            });
        
      } 
  }
```

When i click on login button it send this output in terminal

```
I/flutter (11877): 200
I/flutter (11877): NoSuchMethodError: The method 'setString' was called on null.
I/flutter (11877): Receiver: null
I/flutter (11877): Tried calling: setString("name", "abc")
```

how to fix this issue?

Comment: Try `await` before your sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `myPrefs` is a variable for `SharedPreference` instance then you should know that we must await an Instance of it before we can do anything with it. According to the message in the console `myPrefs` seems to be `null`

Try:

```
var myPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

await myPrefs.setString('name', name);
await myPrefs.setString('email', email);
```

Comment: thankyou, it works, but i want to ask is shared perference is good to use for this scenerio?